# Any method to restore garbled/distorted text file by Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parsing, text

I got a very weird situation that highly needs your assistance. I appreciate your effort and time in advance.

I have a machine which produces a text file that records some information of the machine's working status such as, the coordinate of the drill head and the rotating speed used at that position. While we examine the text file, it appears to be unreadable because most of the contents are garbled. Please see the attached figure. http://ppt.cc/sA1I

If I open it with UltraEdit I see:  http://ppt.cc/TrnV

As you can see some part of the file is readable; however many unrecognizable characters, which should be those numeric values we want.

Two reasons that I believe this problem should be solved by Matlab. First, I am sure this machine has many built-in matlab code inside for analysis purpose. Second, we have a .exe file, which is compiled by Matlab, can restore the garbled text file into arranged and readable format (the values of the coordinates are restored).

We desperately want to see the contents of this file by ourselves. Please kindly provide solution or idea or any direction for me to solve this issue.

Sincerely,

Comment: That's probably not really a text file. Find out the actual format of the file and then you can write code to to read it.

Comment: Could be an encoding issue.

Comment: Try opening it with a better text editor like notepad++.  As @Schorsch mentioned, it may just be an encoding issue

Answer (score 0):

Old question without answer: For the record, a suggestion.

Sounds like a case of [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), a problem with text encoding. Here's how I solved it.

Background: I had text files created on a Mac, others on a Windows, others still on Linux, each in different text encoding. So I got a text editor that would allow me to view the format and to change it. In my case, I used `TextMate` on `MacOS`, opened the files, picked the correct encoding upon opening, which sometimes was a Windows format, a Mac format, sometimes a Latin format -- had to use trial and error to figure it out based on a preview this particular piece of software gave me. Once I had the file opened in the correct encoding, I would save it in the `utf-8`format, which is not platform-specific and allows me to move my text files across various computers.

There may be more scalable methods, but I only had a hundred or so files to deal with, so I opted for the manual method, in order to personally visualize the rendering on screen, and because my files came in different encoding to begin with.